# Why does Figure#show() not work in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have this short matplotlib code for test purposes, but the call to `show()` doesn't do anything, no matter whether I use interactive mode or not. What is the reason for this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
X = np.random.rand(100)
hist, edges = np.histogram(X, bins=16)
xpos = edges[:-1]
ypos = np.zeros_like(edges[:-1])
zpos = ypos
dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(xpos)
dy = dx
dz = hist

ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, zsort='average')
fig.show(warn=True)
```

Comment: `fig.show()` would require the event loop to have already been started. This does not seem to be the case here. To show a pyplot figure, you need to use `pyplot.show()`.

Comment: it works in jupyter using `TkAgg`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I don't want to use the state machine interface and in jupyter, `figure.show()` always works, is there no way to use this API outside jupyter?

Comment: "I don't want to use the state machine interface" - You're using `plt.figure()` so you're using it anyways, no reason to avoid it for showing the figure. `fig.show()` is useful for showing a figure after the figure manager is set and an event loop is started or for showing a pyplot figure from within some other GUI.